# Linux Java application grabs focus when popup open

Tags: java, linux, swing

I'm facing this issue since a while now and only on Linux, Windows works just fine:
With my swing application, whenever a popup is shown, combo-box drop-down for example, it's now longer possible to click anything else to focus and bring it to the front. The Java application seems to grab and consume all events. I need to click inside the application window or press escape to close the popup.
Googling around a bit I found this "-Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true" but that seems to be applicable only when you are in debug mode in some IDE.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how you create the window?

Comment: Actually this affects all popup menus, not a particular case.

Comment: Passing system property -Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true when invoking the JVM the popup doesn't grab the focus anymore but this the right way to go ?